# Byobu F1 help closes current window

Tags: byobu

Somehow when I press F1 byobu opens its help page in the current window. After closing the help page the window is closed.

While working with vim I often hit F1 by accident instead of ESC and my vim session is closed. This is so frustrating..

On my server the byobu help page is opened in a new window when I press F1.

According to the help page the F1 key is `* Used by X11 *`.

How can sort this out/change this?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Did you tried to disable *Byobu F-keys* with `<Shift>F12`?

Comment: On my server its Ubuntu 18.04 and my Laptop is Arch Linux ( I know its the wrong forum)

Comment: Does Byobu launched on Ubuntu Server? Does `<Shift>F12` change the behavior? If it is launched on client (ArchLinux), then it is off-topic here.

Comment: `<Shift>F12` Disables the F1 key also.

Comment: Same for me with, Ubuntu 19.04